# mouseout and mouseleave not working in ie

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, iframe, mouseleave, onmouseout

```
var iframeContent = $("#<%= iframeID %>").contents();
iframeContent.off("mouseover", "#divImgSize").on("mouseover","#divImgSize", function() {
       //some code
    });
```

this function working normal, but

```
iframeContent.off("mouseout", "#divImgSize").on("mouseout", "#divImgSize", function(event) {
    //some code
});
```

or

```
iframeContent.off("mouseleave ", "#divImgSize").on("mouseleave ", "#divImgSize", function(event) {
    //some code
});
```

working in Firefox, Chrome, but not Internet Explorer.

Comment: How is 'iframeContent' defined?

Comment: Please explain exactly your definition of "not working" for this code.

Comment: var iframeContent = $("#<%= iframeTemplate.ClientID %>").contents();

Comment: "not working" - not go inside into the function iframeContent.off("mouseleave ", "#divImgSize").on("mouseleave ", "#divImgSize", function(event) {
    //some code
});

Answer (score 1):

After reviewing another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe) on accessing content of an iframe, the contents must be on the same domain otherwise it's not possible. To make this possible try the following.

```
var iframeContent = $("#<%= iframeID %>").contents();

iframeContent.find("#divImgSize")
    .on("mouseover", doSomeThing())
    .on("mouseleave", doSomeThing());

function doSomeThing(){
    // Your code
}
```

Comment: I found my problem(and solution:) ) in another place